# nodeJs connection with MySql for androidStudio

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

i'm trying to connect Mysql with a files java-script by nodejs.

But i want my server apache send my new data automatically to my app android.

For this I have a table in my database who have for name antenne who return the differents values of this table.
I have already do a script php for connect my app android and my database but  with a script php isn't a callback server

Indeed i want my server push the data in the app android and not the app android who ask the data to my server

My script java

```
var express =require('express');
var mysql=require('mysql');
var app=express();

var connect = mysql.createConnection({
//properties...
host: 'localhost',
user:'root',
passeword;'root',
database'Antenne',
});
 connection.connect(function(error){
 if(!!error){
console.log('Error');
 }else{
  console.log('Connected');
 });

  app.get('/',function(req,resp){
  //aboutmysql
  connection.query("SELECT *FROM antenne"function(error,rows,fields))
   if(!!error){
       console.log('Error in the query');
   }else{
   console.log('Sucessful query');

});
app.listen(80);
```

Comment: you can use [firebase](https://firebase.google.com/) or [socket.io](https://socket.io/)

Comment: and btw tha't not Java, it's JavaScript....

Comment: yea mistake of me thanks ! i found a example of socket.io http://markshust.com/2013/11/07/creating-nodejs-server-client-socket-io-mysql this tuto is great? for connect Mysql to my javascript?

Comment: I prefer to play with ORM, so I use [sequelize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/v3/) to connect my node application with mysql. But if this is your first application you can use the `mysql` library just like in the tutorial. If you want to use `sequelize` you must first learn the basics for [promises](https://www.promisejs.org/)

Comment: oh ok i will see the 2 methods for connect my node with mysql and after extract my json of mysql for make a socket